# Syntax error when try to launch zeppelin, spark with python in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I installed spark and zeppelin, and having trouble running zeppelin. Whenever I try to run shell script with this command
`sh zeppelin-daemon.sh start` , I got this error.

```
sh zeppelin-daemon.sh start
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 26: zeppelin-daemon.sh: [[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 25: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: 
[[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 31: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: 
[[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 35: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: 
[[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 39: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: [[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 43: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: [[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 51: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: [[: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 55: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: 
ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH+=:: not found
zeppelin-daemon.sh: 57: /home/i-06/PycharmProjects/zeppelin/bin/common.sh: 
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

when I install spark and zeppelin, I followed same step as this.

https://gist.github.com/pratos/b2e2937106980a867d0558cba46241b1

my node version is `v4.2.6`, 
mvn version is 
`Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T01:41:47+09:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-91-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: What shell interpreter is linked into sh? it looks like it isn't bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the script directly, i.e. from the Zeppelin dir: `bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start`

The she-bang line in the script will call the correct shell-interpreter.